# FormData object is empty when using vue @submit directive

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I came across some weird edge case and I narrowed it down to a solution. I created a form with vue and empty strings were being sent down to the server. I narrowed it down to the `@submit` directive. If I write `form.addEventListener('submit')` everything works as it should but with the `@submit` directive it does not work.

The solution is to use the addEventListener method but I'm not sure if I did something wrong here or if this is a bug with vue's v-on directive

Runnable example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-izreva?file=index.html

**NOTE**: I know about the form data object and how to view it with

```js
for (const [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value})
}
```

In the below snippet if you uncomment the code then it works with addEventListener.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#test-form')

const app = Vue.createApp({
  name: 'test app',
  methods: {
    test(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(e)

      const formData = new FormData(form)
      for (const [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`)
      }
    }
  }
}).mount('#app-main')

// const form = document.querySelector('#test-form')
// form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
//   e.preventDefault()

//   const formData = new FormData(form)
//   for (const [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
//     console.log(`${key}: ${value}`)
//   }
// })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.47/dist/vue.global.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>app</h1>
    <div id="app-main">
      <form @submit="test" id="test-form">
        <input type="text" name="foo">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <script src="./index.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the `testSubmit()` function is running?

Comment: Yes I tested everything in the console.

Comment: Is the FormData empty (no keys), or does it have keys with empty values for each?

Comment: Have you checked, on the failing case, if there are errors in the console?

Comment: it is logging `foo:` so there are keys but no values

Comment: I just edited the op, there is a runnable example now

Comment: What happens if you do `console.log(document.querySelector("[name='foo']").value);` in `testSubmit()`?

Comment: Sorry, I tried this again and it was not working, I think there must've been a cache issue. I just edited the post and it is indeed from vue and the runnable example is working as it should. `@submit` does not work, `addEventListener('submit')` does work, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine this is an issue with how the CDN version of Vue parses a template from existing HTML.

Each element is replaced with the Vue compiled element equivalent.

The `form` you captured at the start is no longer the one emitting the *submit* event. You can easily check this by comparing `form === e.target`.

If you use the following it works as expected.

```js
const formData = new FormData(e.target);
```

In short, you're doing things in a very *non-Vue* way so it's little surprise you've encountered some friction.

Comment: Yea that fixed it, can you briefly elaborate on this a bit more? Vue looks at the static html and creates it's own copy and that copy is what emits a submit event correct? Is there a more declarative way of doing this if I am stuck using static html? Perhaps using a template ref? I am using shopify and that is why I gotta import vue via cdn

Comment: @dbzx10299 that sounds about right. TBH I haven't looked very closely at the static HTML compiler. A declarative version might be to use _refs_ to keep track of your elements within the Vue component context. That being said, I see no problem using the event target